# LEGO Set identification?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

What does this piece go to?  I bought a lot of LEGO pieces with no instructions and think there may be two sets. I have this mask, or head piece, that is part of a set that I want to look up instructions for.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be part# 64261 from set# 8983, "Vorox".

[image]

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=64261&name=Bionicle%20Mask%20Vorox&category=%5BBionicle,%20Kanohi%20Mask%5D#T=C&C=2

[image]

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8983-1#T=S&O={%22iconly%22:0}

Instructions can be found here:
https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/4547677.pdf

Comment: I was guessing Bionicle myself, but sometimes the category on bricklink surprises me.

Comment: Looks like a good fit for an original Predator too, nice

Comment: @chicks - My oldest loved Bionicle growing up, he still has his collection together and on display.  I don't own a single one, but have their likeness engraved into my memory :)